# Ruby method with two arguments (one has default value) only accepts one

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

I wanted to write a PnP assistant. I created a hash with stats and stat levels, and defined a method to level up those stats. This is my hash:

```
$stats = {
"HP" => 300,
"VIT" => 9,
"STR" => 10,
"DEX" => 15,
"SPD" => 8,
"INT" => 11,
"PSY" => 21,
"HW" => 2,
"MED" => 3,
"SCHW" => 0,
"GEN" => 12,
"RGEW" => 25,
"SELB" => 11,
"MKEN" => 19,
"WILL" => 23
}
```

Below is my method:

```
def level_stat (stat, amount = 1)
  @string = stat.upcase
  print "#{@string}: #{$stats[@string]} > "
  $stats[@string] += 1 * amount
  puts $stats[@string]
  if (@string == "VIT")
    $stats["HP"] += 5 * amount
    print "#{"HP"}: #{$stats["HP"]} > "
    puts $stats["HP"]
  end
end
```

The default value for `amount` levels up the stat by one, but enables to do multiple level ups on the same stat at the same time (or so it's supposed to be). Calling this works as expected:

```
level_stat ("int")
```

However, calling the following statement throws an error:

```
level_stat ("vit", 2)
# >> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
#    level_stat ("vit", 2)
#                     ^
```

I do not understand why it's doing this.

Comment: Don't put space between method name and argument parenthesis.

Comment: Remove the space between `level_stat` and `(` – both when defining the method and when calling it.

Comment: Oof, that's a sad mistake... thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the space between `level_stat` and `(`, or alternatively remove the parentheses completely:

```
level_stat("vit", 2)
level_stat "vit", 2
```

By adding a space *and* parentheses, the ruby parser misinterprets your intention and raises a `SyntaxError`.

If you haven't already, take a quick look through a [ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-parens) -- it would also be common practice to omit the space in the `def`:

```
def level_stat(stat, amount = 1)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Cheers, I thought having spaces between them would be a better style

Comment: @Zitrooone https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-parens

Comment: In addition: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#parens-no-spaces

Comment: I'll thoroughly read that before I post another one of these, thank you

Comment: @Stefan nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

Just for addition to answer of @Tom.

Look:

```
def twice(arg)
  puts arg * 2
end

twice 5 #=> 10
twice(5) #=> 10
twice (5) #=> 10
```

```
def plus(arg1, arg2)
  puts arg1 + arg2
end

plus 2, 2 #=> 4
plus(2, 2) #=> 4
plus (2, 2) #=> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

Ruby parser thinks that `(2, 2)` is a single argument, but `(2, 2)` is not a valid Ruby expression.

Such a situation, when used more than 1 argument. As you see, there is no problem with one argument.

So follow codestyle. Guys gave you link.